# Exception na divisão por zero em Java

Tags: java, exceção, matemática, divisão

Por que isso gera uma ArithmeticException / by zero:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        int a = i / 0;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

E isso não (imprime "Infinity")?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        double a = i / 0.0;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: Eu achei isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954193/why-does-division-by-zero-with-floating-point-or-double-precision-numbers-not

Comment: Depois que eu entendi que dividindo por `0.0` dá infinity. Por isso apaguei minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Isso não é assim só em Java. Isso tem a ver com a representação matemática mesmo. No conjunto dos números inteiros você não tem como representar a divisão inteira por zero. Já no conjunto dos números reais você pode usar técnicas como limite para calcular um certo valor e, nesse caso, quando divide por zero tende ao infinito.
A implementação do Java apenas reflete a matemática.